# Unable to put a variable in Python's print

Tags: python

**My code:**

```
year=[51-52,53,55,56,58,59,60,61]
photo=[{70,72,73},{64,65,68},{79,80,81,82},{74,77,78},{60,61,62},{84,85,87},{57,58,59},{53,54,55,56}]

for i in range(7):
    print "<img src=\"http://files.getdropbox.com/u/100000/Akuja/",year,"/P10104",photo,".JPG\">"
```

I run it and I get

```
File "/tmp/aku.py", line 2
    photo=[{70,72,73},{64,65,68},{79,80,81,82},{74,77,78},{60,61,62},{84,85,87},{57,58,59},{53,54,55,56}]
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I want the following output

```
<img src="http://files.getdropbox.com/u/100000/Akuja/51-52/P1010470.JPG">
<img src="http://files.getdropbox.com/u/100000/Akuja/51-52/P1010472.JPG">
<img src="http://files.getdropbox.com/u/100000/Akuja/51-52/P1010473.JPG">

<img src="http://files.getdropbox.com/u/100000/Akuja/53/P1010464.JPG">
<img src="http://files.getdropbox.com/u/100000/Akuja/53/P1010465.JPG">
<img src="http://files.getdropbox.com/u/100000/Akuja/53/P1010468.JPG">

...
```

I also run the same code with the syntax for list unsuccessfully
    photo={[70,72,73],...}

**How can you make the Python code to work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is your simple solution to your simple problem

```
year=['51-52', '53', '55' , '56' , '58', '59', '60', '61']
photo=[[70,72,73], [64,65,68],[79,80,81,82],[74,77,78],[60,61,62],[84,85,87],[57,58,59],[53,54,55,56]]

for i in range(len(year)):
   for j in range(len(photo[i])):
       print '<img src=\"http://files.getdropbox.com/u/100000/Akuja/%s/P10104%s.JPG>' % (year[i], photo[i][j])
```

Comment: There is some problem in the variable photo, since I get http://dpaste.com/59845/

Comment: @Toby: You are right - the code works. I apparently hit a wrong button in coping the code.

Answer (score 3):

Braces are used to indicate a dictionary (associative array).  You want to use square brackets, which indicates a list.

Also you probably don't want 51-52 in that first line, as that will evaluate to -1.  You should put "51-52" to ensure that it is a string.

Then to get the indexing that you seem to want, you need to do year**[i]** instead of just year, which prints out the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to iterate over years and print photos for that year I would do it this way:

```
year=["51-52","53","55","56","58","59","60","61"]
photo=[(70,72,73),(64,65,68),(79,80,81,82),(74,77,78),(60,61,62),
       (84,85,87),(57,58,59),(53,54,55,56)]

# this dictionary will be generated with the code below
#photos = {
#    "51-52": (70,72,73),
#    "53": (64,65,68),
#    "55": (79,80,81,82),
#    "56": (74,77,78),
#    "58": (60,61,62),
#    "59": (84,85,87),
#    "60": (57,58,59),
#    "61": (53,54,55,56)
#}


photos = {}                         # create photos dictionary

for y in xrange(len(year)):
    photos[year[y]] = photo[y]

years = photos.keys()               # sort the years
years.sort()

for year in years:
    for photo in photos[year]:
        print "<img src=\"http://files.getdropbox.com/u/100000/Akuja/"+year+"/P10104"+str(photo)+".JPG\">"
```

You get:

```
<img src="http://files.getdropbox.com/u/100000/Akuja/51-52/P1010470.JPG">
<img src="http://files.getdropbox.com/u/100000/Akuja/51-52/P1010472.JPG">
<img src="http://files.getdropbox.com/u/100000/Akuja/51-52/P1010473.JPG">
<img src="http://files.getdropbox.com/u/100000/Akuja/53/P1010464.JPG">
<img src="http://files.getdropbox.com/u/100000/Akuja/53/P1010465.JPG">
<img src="http://files.getdropbox.com/u/100000/Akuja/53/P1010468.JPG">
```

I would store photos and years in dictionary as shown above but if you have years and photos in separate lists (as in your question) you can create the photos like this, note years are in quotes "":

```
photos = {}

for y in xrange(len(year)):
    photos[year[y]] = photo[y]
```

Comment: The functions .keys() and .sort() are great.